# Using directive scope attribute value inside directive controller (not template)

Tags: angularjs-directive

New to AngularJS and I'm having difficulty understanding some of the finer points of directives.  I have a scenario for which I want to use a directive without transclusion (I think?), using the value of an attribute for the directive inside the directive's isolate controller to fetch additional data to provide to the directive's template...  (Hopefully that mouthful words came out right?).

Maybe this pseudo example will make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve:

**someDirective.js:**

```
angular.module('someDirective', [
    'someService',
])

.directive('someDirective', function() {
    function SomeController($scope, someService) {
        $scope.additionalData = someService.getStuff(/* ??? I want to use 'someKey' here */);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: SomeController,
        scope: {
            someKey: '='
        },
        template: '{{additionalData | json}}'
    };
});
```

**directiveUser.tpl.html:**

```
<someDirective someKey="someKeyFromTheOuterScope"/>
```

Note that my directive's template has no need to use the key value directly, but rather additional data supplied by the directive's controller.

All the documentation I've read either uses the supplied scope attribute data directly in the template, or via the 'attrs' parameter of a directive's link function.  I don't think link is what I want, as I'm not manipulating the DOM and instead merely wanting to provide additional data to the directive's template.

What am I fundamentally misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the scope to get the value of someKey, if I understand correctly... Try this out:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.outerScopeKey = 'outer scope key';
})
.service('someService', function() {
    this.getStuff = function(someKey) {
        return someKey;
    };
})
.directive('someDirective', function() {
    function SomeController($scope, someService) {
        $scope.additionalData = someService.getStuff($scope.someKey);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: SomeController,
        scope: {
            someKey: '='
        },
        template: '{{ additionalData | json }}'
    };
});
```

And your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <some-directive some-key="outerScopeKey"/>
</div>
```

So the custom directive sits inside of another controller, and data from the controller (outer scope) is passed into the directive, which is then passed onto a service.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1h9as6q/)

Comment: Looks like my problem was incorrect parameter name denormalization in the containing HTML fragment (my posting here was simplified from my actual files).  Thanks for confirming that what I was fundamentally trying to do was as straight forward as I thought it should have been.